# How programmatically create a public Message Queue in remote machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, message-queue

I built a Windows Service to create a public queue. 
 
If I create the queue in local machine, it's ok. 
But if the queue is in another machine in the intranet, an exception is thrown.

```
MessageQueue.Create(@"remotemachinename\testQueue");
```

The exception:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
  Source=Stoque.Abaris.Scheduler.Core
  StackTrace:
       em Stoque.Abaris.Scheduler.Core.Actions.JobActions.Create(JobDetail jobDetail, Type jobType) na C:\Pessoal\Projetos\WCFQueue\Stoque.Abaris.Scheduler.Core\Actions\JobActions.cs:linha 60
       em Stoque.Abaris.Scheduler.Email.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) na C:\Pessoal\Projetos\WCFQueue\Stoque.Abaris.Scheduler.Email\Startup.cs:linha 35
  InnerException: null
```

Do I need some configuration in the Active Directory or user permission?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like permissions are you running your windows service as an account which has access to create a message in the remote Queue?

Comment: The following post may have some suggestions for resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874631/access-to-message-queuing-system-is-denied